# How to pass dynamic image path in Twitter Card?

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-card

I am using

```
<?php $image='http://abc.in/def.jpg'; ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
        <meta name="og:image" content="<?php echo $image?>">
        <meta name="og:description" content="<?php echo $description; ?>">
        <meta name="og:title" content="<?php echo $title; ?>">
        <meta name="twitter:url" content="http://keyss.in">
        <meta name="twitter:app:id:iphone" content="">
        <meta name="twitter:app:id:ipad" content="">
        <meta name="twitter:app:id:googleplay" content="">
        <meta name="twitter:app:url:iphone" content="">
        <meta name="twitter:app:url:ipad" content="">
        <meta name="twitter:app:url:googleplay" content="">
    </head>
</html>
```

code for my Twitter post.

When I pass static content in `<meta name="og:image" content="http://abc.in/def.jpg">`
image is posted on my Twitter wall, but if I pass variable as 
`<meta name="og:image" content="<?php echo $image?>">`
image is not posted on my wall.

How can I pass dynamic variable in image content?

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after echo $image, but the code looks correct otherwise. What is the output?

Comment: I have tried semicolon also but not working

Comment: @Happy what `echo $image` outputs? show it here.

Answer (score 0):

The missing semicolon after $image could be the issue (as mentioned in the comments):

```
    <meta name="og:image" content="<?php echo $image; ?>">
    <meta name="og:description" content="<?php echo $description; ?>">
    <meta name="og:title" content="<?php echo $title; ?>">
```

Once you've fixed the code, run the Page through the [Twitter Card validator](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator) to make sure everything appears correctly. It should hopefully give you an idea of what's going wrong.