# Is it possible to tweet dynamic images or text?

Tags: twitter, dynamic, twitter-card

I'm trying to find a way to tweet a countdown timer, which would require some way to dynamically update either text or an image or animation over the course of weeks to months. But really, this is just a single instance of a more general problem: is there a way to post any sort of dynamically updating content to Twitter?

It strikes me that the answer is most likely "no" with respect to regular user tweets, since you obviously can't embed arbitrary JavaScript in a tweet, and since (IIRC) Twitter caches images you tweet, at least for long periods of time. Is this perhaps possible with Twitter Cards, backed by a custom site?

Comment: You can probably pass dynamic images to twitter cards, but this would only update at most upon each page load. Looks like [This person](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22243526/how-to-pass-dynamic-image-path-in-twitter-card) found a way to pass dynamic image paths, so I don't see why not dynamic images.

Comment: I'll have to play around with it some, but it looks to me like that answer makes a card with a new image url when the card is generated, rather than each time the card is loaded in a Twitter feed, since I *think* cards are cached in Twitter's servers once generated (though I could be wrong)